# How to show the current printer in a label when the UserForm starts?

Tags: vba, excel, printing, userform

I have set up a VBA form for the user to print a report with options. I want to display the active printer on that form using a label. When I launch the form it displays the active printer text "default printer". That label will only update to the active printer if I click on it. I have not been able to find a way to run that macro label when the form starts.

The code below is what I am using to display the active printer. I know its procedure is based on a click option. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Private Sub CurrentPrinterLabel_Click()
    CurrentPrinterLabel.Caption = Application.ActivePrinter
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code under the UserForm's `Initialize` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CurrentPrinterLabel.Caption = Application.ActivePrinter
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Activate` event if you want the label to be updated each time the form is activated.

### References:

- [`Initialize` Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/initialize-event).
- [`Activate`, `Deactivate` Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/activate-deactivate-events).

Comment: I cant believe I did not think of that. Simple. Thank you!